# Exploding column with index

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql

I know that I can "explode" a column of type array like this:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.explode
val explodedDf = 
    payloadLegsDf.withColumn("legs", explode(payloadLegsDf.col("legs")))
```

Now I have multiple rows; one for each item in the array.

Is there a way I can "explode with index"?  So that there will be a new column that contains the index of the item in the original array?

(I can think of hacks to do this.  First make the array field into an array of tuples of the original value and the index.  Then do the explode.  Then unpack the tuples.  But is there a more elegant way?)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extracting array index in Spark Dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49195920/extracting-array-index-in-spark-dataframe)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you are using Spark 2.1+, the [`posexplode`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$) function can be used for that:

> Creates a new row for each element with position in the given array or map column.

Example:

```
val df = Seq(
  (1L, Array[String]("a", "b")),
  (2L, Array[String]("c", "d"))
).toDF("id", "items")

val res = df.select($"id", posexplode($"items"))
```

This will create two new columns, `pos` for position/index and `col` for the extracted value:

```
+---+---+---+
| id|pos|col|
+---+---+---+
|  1|  0|  a|
|  1|  1|  b|
|  2|  0|  c|
|  2|  1|  d|
+---+---+---+
```